# Should I use a session with p12-certificate

Tags: python-requests, pkcs#12, p12

So I've writren a scraper that uses the [requests_pkcs12-library](https://pypi.org/project/requests-pkcs12/) and a .p12-cert.

Currently I'm making a lot a requests where I use it as described in the docs

```
from requests_pkcs12 import get

r = get('https://example.com/test', pkcs12_filename='clientcert.p12', pkcs12_password='correcthorsebatterystaple')
```

The docs also show that you can use it in a session instead.

```
from requests import Session 
from requests_pkcs12 import Pkcs12Adapter 

session = Session()
session.mount('https://example.com', Pkcs12Adapter(pkcs12_filename='clientcert.p12', pkcs12_password='correcthorsebatterystaple')) 
r = session.get('https://example.com/test')
```

So this works fine as well. But what are the advantages of doing so? Does it put less presure on the server which it authenticates with?

It does not seem to be adding an authenticated cookie to the session so I was wondering why the one would be prefered over the other.

Does anyone know this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using a session may improve performance on client-side and reduce the server-side load as well.

Note that this has almost nothing to do with the `requests_pkcs12` library, but is a generic mechanism of the `requests` library.

The [`requests` manual](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/) states:

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and will use urllib3’s [connection pooling](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/index.html#module-urllib3.connectionpool). So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)).

The linked Wikipedia entry for [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) states:

> Advantages
>
> - ...
> - Reduced [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU) usage and round-trips because of fewer new connections and [TLS handshakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake).

And the Wikipedia section on [TLS handshakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake) states:

> **Client-authenticated TLS handshake**
>
> ...
>
> 1. Negotiation Phase:
>
>    - ...
>    - The server sends a CertificateRequest message, to request a certificate from the client so that the connection can be mutually authenticated.
>    - ...
>    - The client responds with a Certificate message, which contains the client's certificate.

To summarize, using a `requests` session leads to connection pooling which leads to fewer TCP connections and hence fewer TLS handshakes, which in turn means fewer client certificate authentications. Note that this is independent on how the client certificate was made available to `requests`, whether in PKCS12 format (using `requests_pkcs12`) or PEM format (using plain `requests`).